# Static not existing though being declared in nginx default config

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to get my static files accessible so that I can load them with Flask.

ex: https://example.com/static/render.css

I've included this in the https part of my site:

```
location /static/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias /root/site/static;
}
```

But it just returns a 403 always.
The directory is correct and all, I've also ran the `chown -R /root/site/static/` command. Idk what's the issue.

Nginx is definitely doing something with the data though, as all other extensions just reply a badgateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just write my CSS inline.